# How can I access a property of the base class of another base class?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

Suppose, I have the following situation:

```
class TopBaseClass:
    ... ...
    ... ...
    @property
    def top_property(self):
        return self.__top_property
    
    @top_property.setter
    def top_property(self, top_property):
        self.__top_property = top_property

class IntermediateBaseClass(TopBaseClass):
    ...

class LowestClass(IntermediateBaseClass):
    ... ...
    ... ...
    def lowest_function(self):
        something = ""

        ... ...
         
        return something
```

Now, I want to access `top_property` from `lowest_function()`.

How can I do that?

I tried the following and didn't work:

```
something = str(super().super().top_property)
```

It gives me an error.

So, how to do that?

Comment: Just use `self.top_property`. That's how inheritance works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do:

```
something = self.top_property
```

The attribute is part of your instance and can be directly referenced.   the getter will be used to retrieve the value.

Comment: when to use `super()` then?

Comment: use super when a method name is overridden.  so if you have a method or attribute  in the super class and the same named member in your subclass,   you would use super to get call the one in the base class (it forces the reference to go there rather than the subclass)